# android re active typing in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext, i want it to be not editable at first, so i did this

```
et_more.setKeyListener(null);
```

when a user select radiobutton i want to re active the edittext again

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.rb_dialog_price_limit_more:

            break;
        case R.id.rb_dialog_price_limit_less:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

that was the onclick , what should i put inside `case` `break` please?

#### I want to make it active again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `et_more.setKeyListener(null);`

You can try `et_more.setEnabled(false);` and in your switch put `et_more.setEnabled(true);`